# C# Visual Studio Windows Forms Error CS1501

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make a pc diagnostic tool I did so in command prompt and I am trying to do so in windows forms the IDE I am using is Visual Studio 2015 sorry if the question is obvious or irrelevant I am new at C# I looked around but could not find anything useful to deal with this error
-thanks Mahmood

Here is the working Command prompt code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace mahmoodspcdiagnostictool_m.p.d.t_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("To begin diagnostic type start diagnostic");
            string startdiagnostic = Console.ReadLine();
            if (startdiagnostic == "start diagnostic")
            {
                PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

                PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

                Console.WriteLine("Cpu Usage: Avalible RAM:");
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2500);
                    Console.Write("{0}%", perfCpuCount.NextValue());
                    Console.WriteLine("     {0} MB", perfMemCount.NextValue());
                }
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the not working Windows Forms code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace MahmoodsPCDiagnosticTool_M.P.D.T__GUI_Edition_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        //When the start button is clicked this code is to be executed
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox4.AppendText("{0}%\r\n", perfCpuCount.NextValue());
            richTextBox5.AppendText("{0} MB\r\n", perfMemCount.NextValue());
        }

       private void Form1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is a pc diagnostic tool it was made by Mahmood Badr.");
        }

        private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: I am glad someone solved it. But next time please include any errors you get so we are able to assist you better. "It is not working" does not tell us much, nor does "it gives me an error" without the error details.

Comment: Please either revert your edit or delete the question. The text "This question has been deleted question." does not help anyone.

Comment: If you want the post gone. Feel free to unaccept the answer and delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows you using a richTextBox, which doesn't have an `AppendText(string, string)` method, only an `AppendText(string)` method.

This works:

```
PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

//When the start button is clicked this code is to be executed
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox4.AppendText($"{perfCpuCount.NextValue()}%{Environment.NewLine}");
    richTextBox5.AppendText($"{perfMemCount.NextValue()} MB{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

*with C#7.0